# Как сделать так, чтобы библиотека на python читала файл из директории, из которой ее импортируют?

Tags: python-3.x

У меня имеется библиотека, загруженная на pip. В библиотеке есть скрипт, который должен читать файл из директории, из которой импортировали библиотеку. Как это сделать?

Пример:
Библиотека находится в /Users/a
Если библиотеку импортируют из директории /Users/b, то и читать файл она должна из этой директории

Т.е по сути вопрос заключается в получении правильного путя

Comment: Приведите лучше кодом. А почему нельзя в ту библиотеку передать путь?